# I want to change the bitmap source image stored in drawable folder

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change the bitmap image in the xml file which is in the drawable folder manually through java code. Please help me with that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bebe" android:gravity="center"android:alpha="0.1"/>
</item>

<item android:top="300dp"
    android:bottom="-300dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="-300dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-10"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="?android:colorBackground"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

}
```

This is the main activity through which the background file is linked:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="@drawable/background" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/background"
android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-100dp">

<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:id="@+id/iv"
android:src="@drawable/bebe_pp"
app:civ_border_color="@color/semiTransparentWhite"
app:civ_border_width="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:text="Bebe Rexha"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:id="@+id/tv" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:text="musician, singer, songwriter"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:id="@+id/tv2" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
app:theme="@style/TransparentBar">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="About"
android:textSize="24sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The drawable folder is read only. But.. Where is your code trying so?

Comment: Can you name the image? Instead of dumping a lot of xml files here.

Comment: is there any other way to get those effects which are caused by the file?

Comment: Which effects? Which file? Where are you talking about? It is very unclear what you want.

Comment: image name is written in the xml.

Comment: And you are too lazy to tell us which name or id?

Comment: that first xml contains an <item> tag, it has a bitmap tag in it, i want to change that image manually. If u got my point!!

Comment: You cannot change a file which is in the drawable folder. The folder is read only.